# How can I apply jQuery table stripes after dynamically adding new rows?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble figuring out how to maintain my table stripes after adding new rows to a table. If I change the `.insertAfter()` selector to `#names tr:last` it works as I would expect, however using `tr:first` or `tr:nth-child(x)` results in the new row and all rows below it being striped. When looking at the updated DOM in Chrome's developer tools everything looks normal. I'm hoping someone can explain to me why this isn't working. I feel like I must be missing something fundamental. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .striped {
                background-color: #silver;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function stripes () {
                $("tr:even").each(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("striped");
                });
            }

            $(function () {
                stripes();
                $("#addRow").click(function () {
                    $("<tr><td>Kenny</td><td>Bania</td></tr>").insertAfter("#names tr:first");
                    stripes();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="addRow">Add Row</a>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="names">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jerry</td>
                        <td>Seinfeld</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Elaine</td>
                        <td>Benes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>George</td>
                        <td>Costanza</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cosmo</td>
                        <td>Kramer</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove **.striped** class first.

```
function stripes () {
            $("tr").each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("striped");
            });
            $("tr:even").each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("striped");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Wow that should have been apparent. Thank you!

Comment: Why are we calling each? jQuery doesn't need to iterate over the entire collection. $('tr').removeClass('striped'); $('tr:even').addClass('striped'); is all you need